# Set innerhtml of a div echoed by php

Tags: javascript, php, dom

I created a div element using php echo

```
*//some html code*
*<?php echo "<div id = "randomDiv"></div>" ?>
<script>
     document.getElementById("randomDiv").innerHTML = "Hey";
</script>*
```

but this does not manipulate the innerHTML of the div. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: you should get a syntax error

Comment: you need to escape your quotes : `<?php echo "<div id = \"randomDiv\"></div>" ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Double quote for **`div id`** makes it invalid. Try changing the quote to single quote:

```
<?php echo "<div id='randomDiv'></div>"; ?>
<script>
     document.getElementById("randomDiv").innerHTML = "Hey";
</script>
```